# wifi networking

Tags: networking, wireless

In my notebook, wifi is connected at startup, and suddenly disconnects after few minutes. Again connects when re-started. I tried so many things on various recommendations, but no avail. Wifi name appears in Network Manager.

Comment: It's 14.04 ver.  Wifi works with external wifi adapter (Netgear).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so far I haven't got an answer. But I tried. Finally got a solution.
See below. So many thanks to chili555.
Now i have a stable WiFi connection.

First find out your wireless network adapter (eg. rtl8723be)
and replace that of the script.

I suggest you try a driver parameter. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
modprobe -r rtl8723be
modprobe rtl8723be
exit
```

It may take a reboot. Any improvement?
shareimprove this answer

answered Oct 30 '14 at 14:01
chili555
18.5k21947

Many thanks chili555.
May this help others too.
By the way I suggest this should go as an update to Ubuntu 14.04